# My account just got deleted; how do I restore?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I had lots of reputation points on some Stack Exchange sites, and my account just got deleted, without me knowing.

Can I restore it, and if I can, how?

Comment: Use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page and explain in detail ...

Comment: Also please clarify, on what site your account is deleted?

Comment: OK, that's weird... why OP account is deleted? Just trolling, wasting our time??

Answer (score 3):

#### Can I restore it (my deleted account), and if I can, how?

You cannot restore it yourself. The StackExchange Team may be able to help.

Use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page, select "Other" and explain in detail ...