# Automatic comment was not added when voting to close as duplicate

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

I voted to close [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283078/my-account-just-got-deleted-how-do-i-restore) as a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22568/is-it-possible-to-recover-an-account-deleted-at-the-se-team-level). By the time of voting to close, there wasn't any comment linking to that question, and it didn't appear in the "Linked" section.

However, no auto comment was posted:

> [image]

I added a manual comment later, but can someone please look into what failed in the auto comment process?

Might be relevant, that I have a [support](/questions/tagged/support) gold badge, but the hammer (aka, using the gold badge to close on my own) wasn't used since I put that tag myself prior to closing. I am 100% sure this didn't stop automatic comments before though.

Comment: Hmm, no repro for me ...

Comment: @rene yeah, it was most likely a temporary glitch, but hoping a dev can see something and hopefully prevent the next case. (or maybe something changed with hammer code, which is why I added the last paragraph.)

Comment: Given the age of the post in question, this seems unlikely, but a [deleted possible duplicate comment appears to block auto creation of a new one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250193/wheres-my-possible-duplicate-auto-comment)

Comment: @psubsee2003 good call, missed that one as I'm not very active on MSO. Might be the case, someone might have mentioned that other question in a comment (without voting to close) and regretted it for some reason, deleting his/her comment. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of earlier today, we ignore deleted comments when checking to see if a "possible duplicate" comment already exists.

(Technically speaking, we look for any comment that links to the proposed duplicate, automated or not.)